# Angular: Event listener to dynamic element from external lib

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I have implemented some input typeahead autocomplete from bootstrap in my input element it also have a switchable lang (right to left and left to right).

The default of the dropdown menu is `text-align: left` and its created dynamically when typing. I'm trying to attach an eventListener to it when it's on the RTL input it will override its css to `text-align: right` and back to left if it's on LTR.

I tried this for each ltr/rtl:

```
let dd_element = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-menu')[0]
dd_element.classList.add('dropdown-toLeft')
```

But I get undefined error since the element is not exist yet

So.. How can I control the dynamic element and it's behavior?

Comment: When switching to the rtl language, does the `dir` attribute get set anywhere in the html? Potentially you could solve it with just css: `[dir="rtl"] .dropdown-menu { text-align: right!important; }`

Comment: the element is not created yet so if I try to change something I got undefined

Comment: If you target the dropdown element with CSS, it won't matter whether the element exists or not. The CSS rule will be applied whenever the element is created. Can you post the HTML markup for the dropdown element for ltr and rtl?

Comment: I tried it out, but it wont affect when I'm switching the components